# How to Transform JMS message to JSON for DataMapper

Tags: jms, mule

I am sending the following json message to a flow via JMS:

[{"salesOrderId":"00001-2-3","saleName":"Car Sale","status":"processing"}, {"salesOrderId":"00004-5-6","saleName":"House Sale","status":"processing"}]

this is my strategy:

```
    <flow name="integration-consumer-client2" doc:name="integration-consumer-client2">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="client2.queue" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS"/>
    <logger message="Consumes Client 2 = #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <logger message="Client 2 Correlation = #[message.correlationId]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="response" doc:name="VM"/>
</flow>
<flow name="integration-consumer-client" doc:name="integration-consumer-client">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint doc:name="JMS" connector-ref="Active_MQ" queue="client1.queue">
    </jms:inbound-endpoint>
    <logger message="Consumes Client = #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <logger message="Client Correlation = #[message.correlationId]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="response" doc:name="VM"/>      
</flow>  
<flow name="integration-flow" doc:name="integration-flow">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="response" doc:name="VM">
         <message-properties-transformer>
            <add-message-property key="MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE" value="2" />
        </message-properties-transformer>
        <collection-aggregator/>
    </vm:inbound-endpoint>
    <logger message="after vm = #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
     <request-reply doc:name="Request-Reply">
        <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="queue.validation" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS">
             <jms:object-to-jmsmessage-transformer doc:name="Object to JMSMessage"/>
        </jms:outbound-endpoint>
        <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="queue.validation.response" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS"/>
    </request-reply>
    <logger message="Siebel Response in ESB = #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

So two consumers messages are aggregated and then sent to another flow via the request reply using JMS. in that flow the message comes through as 
[{"salesOrderId":"00001-2-3","saleName":"Car Sale","status":"processing"}, {"salesOrderId":"00004-5-6","saleName":"House Sale","status":"processing"}]

and the flow:

```
    <jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" username="admin" password="admin" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ"/>
<data-mapper:config name="JSON_To_JSON" transformationGraphPath="json_to_json.grf" doc:name="JSON_To_JSON"/>
<flow name="validation-flow" doc:name="validation-flow">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint doc:name="JMS" connector-ref="Active_MQ" queue="queue.validation" >
        <jms:jmsmessage-to-object-transformer doc:name="JMSMessage to Object"/>    
    </jms:inbound-endpoint>

    <logger message="Payload = #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <data-mapper:transform config-ref="JSON_To_JSON" doc:name="JSON To JSON"/>
    <logger message="inside siebel after mapper = #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

I want to send the data through a mapper because i would like to change the status to "Complete". but after the json to json mapper the result is [B@2b9f82b. How can i transform the jms message to be more readable for the mapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a perfectly valid bytearray. You can convert it to String again using a object-to-string-transformer or even better a byte-array-to-string-transformer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, if i put a object-to-string or a byte-array-to-string transformer after the mapper i get the following payload = [ ]

Comment: Then your datamapper transformation is wrong and it's returnung nothing. I would start reviewing the *element mapping* (top-center of the dialog).

Comment: Managed to solve it by doing a json-to-map data mapper and then after the mapper using a object-to-json transformer. for some strange reason this works. thanks for your help

Comment: You're welcome. The json-to-map should not be necessary, I would double check the input type in your original approach for a faster solution.

Comment: thanks! it only only works if i add a splitter, map object to object instead of array to array. so after the mapping i have to aggregate the payload again

Comment: If you need to split, then you have a problem with the cardinality, please check at the datamapper dialog, at the top-center, somethong called **element mapping**, this handles the cardinality or stablish that you are receiving a collection when creating the map.
Also if you find the answer satisfactory, please mark it as resolved.